# How to solve a cyclic project dependency in Eclipse. Any way to make one of the dependencies runtime only?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, circular-dependency

I have a project that basically consists of 2 modules. I have a Eclipse workspace and 2 java projects (maven) in it which represent those two modules.

To go a bit more in depth:

- **Project 1**: Core Module (Has Core Implementation and API Interfaces)
- **Project 2**: Auxiliary Module (A Server)

**Project 2** requires to have **Project 1** as Dependency in order to access the API Interfaces during compile time. But the problem is that **Project 1** requires **Project 2** in order to work properly (This is only a runtime requirement though).

So when I add in each project the other project as dependency a cyclic dependency error is shown, as Eclipse doesn't knows in which order to compile the classes.

The way I managed to make this work is that I added the "bin" folder from **Project 2** as dependency to **Project 1** as also all of **Project 2** dependencies (Which are maven based). This though makes the whole project completely bound to my system, as all paths are adjusted to my computer setup.

Is there any proper way to specify another project to be dependency only on "runtime", and not on "compile" and avoid the cyclic redundancy in Eclipse?

---

To explain in a more visual way. What I need is:

- **Project 2** --- During compilation depends on ---> **Project 1**
- **Project 1** --- During runtime depends on ---> **Project 2**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Eclipse can handle circular project dependencies** but by default circular dependencies will be reported as an error for good reasons (splitting code into projects with circular dependencies makes no sense).

You can **decrease the circular dependencies project problem severity from *Error* to *Warning*** for both projects as follows (not recommended):

1. In ***Project > Properties: Java Compiler > Building***

   1. check the checkbox ***Enable project specific settings*** and
   2. in the section *Build path problems* choose for ***Circular dependencies*** ***Warning*** instead of *Error*

Answer (score 1):

So based on @JF-Meier's comments, I found another way how to make this work. The whole idea was basically to have **Project 2** loosely coupled to **Project 1**, to allow **Project 2** to be swapped with other implementations, while still being a vital part to **Project 1** to work.

To solve the circular dependency issue, I've just created another project that sets **Project 1** and **Project 2** as it's dependency, and from there I launch **Project 1**. This solved the circular dependency issue for me and everything works.

The result:

- **Project 0**: Launcher to start Project 1
- **Project 1**: Core Module (Has Core Implementation and API Interfaces)
- **Project 2**: Auxiliary Module (A Server)

And the dependencies:

- **Project 1** --- Depends on nothing
- **Project 2** --- Depends on ---> **Project 1**
- **Project 0** --- Depends on ---> **Project 1** and **Project 2**

And like this I can launch **Project 1** from **Project 0** while having **Project 2** on the classpath (So **Project 1** can find **Project 2** as required).

I marked the response from @howlger as accepted as it also fixed my issue. But in case my question was not well understantable, I'm putting here how I finally fixed it, in case it may be helpfull for somebody else trying to achieve the same like me.

Thanks for all the help as always here!

Answer (score 0):

In Maven, dependencies have a scope. They can be declared as "compile", "runtime", "test" etc.

You can declare a compile dependency on Project1 in Project2 and a runtime dependency in Project1 on Project2. I have never tried to define dependencies in such a way, but it will probably work.

But, much more important: If Project1 cannot be used without Project2 and vice versa, why are they different projects?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to add an Eclipse project as Maven dependency.

Comment: The reason why Project2 comes separately is because it's swappable. In my case its a Server implementation based on NanoHTTPD, but other implementations using Jetty, Spark or whatever else may be included. Each have different stability and memory footprint. That's why it's useful in my case to allow to use different implementations. I find these different implementations using reflex.

Comment: About your first comment: I thought all your eclipse projects are managed with Maven. If not, think about doing it.

Comment: About the second comment: So Project1 does not _really_ depend on Project2, but on some project that implements certain interfaces (I guess). So Project2 is no runtime dependency of Project1. Instead, there are different possibles combinations. If you have dependency from Project2 on Project1, you should be able to start Project2. Project1 probably does not need to know anything about Project2.